# Overleaf always renders non-selected tex file on initial load and compile

Tags: compiling, overleaf

I have an overleaf project where I'm writing solutions for an annual math contest. Here is my file structure:

[image: Overleaf File Structure]
You can see that I have a "previous" folder with my solutions to past years and the current one I'm working on is outside of it. However, when I open up my project the pdf compilation on the right side always compiles the old one (Y31R1.tex) even though on the left side the new one (Y31R1.tex) is selected.

What's even stranger is that the diagrams on the pdf are the ones in Y32R1.tex so the pdf shows the text for the old doc and the diagrams for the new one. Is this a cache issue?

This is a small problem but it's still annoying. Any help appreciated.

~Shrey J.

Comment: Did you specify the correct file as main in the menu?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean or how you can do that.

Comment: Oh I got it now thank you very much!

Comment: In the top left of the page, above the “new file” icon there is an icon with overleaf symbol, this is the menu. In the settings section is where you choose a main file

Comment: Seems a little off topic for Tex.Se

Comment: Where else would I ask the question?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it with the help of Luis Turcio.

"In the top left of the page, above the “new file” icon there is an icon with overleaf symbol, this is the menu. In the settings section is where you choose a main file"